# Analytic sets are rectifiable

Tags: reference-request, geometric-measure-theory

I am looking for a reference on the statement that real analytic sets (i.e. sets in the form
$u^{-1}(0)$ where $0\not\equiv u:E\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is analytic, or finite intersections of sets of this type for several analytic functions)
are $(n-1)$-rectifiable (in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set).

I know this result is supposed to be found somewhere in Federer's Geometric measure theory, but the language of the book is too complex for me so I am having a hard time finding it and translating it in the simple terms of the above definitions.

EDIT: I believe the result is contained  here (Federer's GMT, Theorem 3.4.8(13))
[image]

The main problem is understanding $\dim \alpha$, which is defined in a very complicated way in terms of ideals. If I could understand why $\dim \alpha\leq n-1$ when $\alpha$ is the germ of an analytic set, that would be enough.

Comment: Do you mean $m$-rectifiable by rectifiable (and for what $m$)?

Comment: @Skeeve yes, for $m=n-1$, I've edited.

Comment: but then if $u \equiv 0$ and e.g. $n=2$ then $u^{-1}(0) = \mathbb R^2$ is not $1$-recifiable (even countably).

Comment: @Skeeves I've added the assumption that $u\not \equiv 0$, it should be the only pathological case.

Comment: I think the answer is essentially contained [in Proposition 3 here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07276).

Comment: @Skeeve It says that the dimension is $\leq n-1$, but how does that imply that it is rectifiable?

Comment: In general finiteness of the Hausdorff measure of a set does not imply rectifiability, as far as I remember. But the cited note actually shows that $u^{-1}(0)$ can be covered by countably many graphs of $C^1$ functions from $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ to $\mathbb R^n$ (see the [proofs of claims 2 and 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07276)).

Comment: @Skeeve Yes, but rectifiability also requires that this covering only 'differs' from the original set 'by measure zero'. The proof says that $u^{-1}(0)\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}}\left\{x\in E:\partial^{\alpha}u(x)=0, \nabla (\partial^{\alpha})(x)\neq 0\right\}$, but how do I know that those sets satisfy that property with respect to the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure? I mean, the derivatives of $u$ can definitely vanish in a nonzero $(n-1)$-dimensional measure set outside of $u^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Rectifiability of a set $F$ requires a covering up to a null set, i.e. ${F\setminus \bigcup _{i=0}^{\infty }f_{i}\left(\mathbb {R} ^{m}\right)}$ should be null (in particular it can be empty), not the symmetric difference ${F\mathop{\triangle} \bigcup _{i=0}^{\infty }f_{i}\left(\mathbb {R} ^{m}\right)}$.

Comment: @Skeeve You're right, I misread the definition. I had immediately assumed it didn't make sense this way, considering that in the case $m=n$ we can just take $f$ to be the identity map which implies that any set is $n$-rectifiable. But I guess it's how it's meant to be. Thank you!